# MS Access multiple left joins

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to do two left joins and getting either a Syntax error or Missing operator error. I have 3 tables (DFM, Audit, Accounting Calendar).  I want to left join Audit and  Accounting Calendar table into DFM table (main table)

Here is my current coding in Access:

```
FROM (([DFM report] 

LEFT JOIN [Audit report] ON [DFM report].URN = [Audit report].URN)

LEFT JOIN [Accounting Calendar] ON [DFM report].Receipt Date = [Accounting 
Calendar].Date
```

Comment: Where is your `SELECT` clause

Comment: Its a pretty big select statement with multiple calculation and IFF statements. This was working perfectly with the first left join. As soon as i added the 3rd table (Accounting Calendar) and tried the 2nd left join, I started getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the `SELECT` clause in there.

There's two errors I can see:

- You have two open brackets, and only one closed.
- You have not enclosed `Receipt Date` in square brackets.

The SQL should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM ([DFM report] LEFT JOIN [Audit report] ON [DFM report].URN = [Audit report].URN)
                   LEFT JOIN [Accounting Calendar] ON [DFM report].[Receipt Date] = [Accounting Calendar].Date
```

Note:  `Date` isn't a great name for a field as it's also a reserved word for Access.

Comment: Okay the error is completely gone now, but when i try to bring month name from my accounting calendar table using date, i get empty month field

Comment: Do you mean `MonthName(Month([Date]))` where `Date` is the name of the field, and the field is a `Date/Time` data type?

Comment: So DFM table has many rows with Date (e.g 1/2/2017). Accounting Calendar table has two fields. One field is the date similar to DFM date format (using this to join the two table), the other field is the Month (e.g Jan, Feb, Mar etc). So end result should be too see Accounting Calendar month beside DFM date. At the moment, the month field beside DFM date is showing nothing

Comment: Does either date include a time portion?  Does `INT([DFM report].[Receipt Date]) = INT([Accounting Calendar].Date)` fix it?

Comment: Yes DFM date includes time but the Accounting Calendar doesn't. I tried INT and now im getting error "The expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated"

Comment: Actually it worked now!   Although the query is taking a bit longer to run.

Comment: Good.  You can probably remove the `INT` from around the Accounting Calendar.  The query will run faster if you can remove the time from dates in Account Calendar.  Just wondering if any values contain `NULL`?  That could cause a problem when trying to convert using `INT`?  Maybe `INT(NZ([DFM report].[Receipt Date],0))`, but that could slow it down even further.

Comment: Accounting Calendar doesnt have a time, DFM date has time and its a huge table with many rows. Maybe I can do a one time change and  use INT under "Append" tab and this way i can remove the time from there, and run the query without INT?

Comment: Yes, if Accounting Calendar doesn't have time you don't need the INT - it just removes the time portion from the date/time.  You could update the dates in the DFM report and not bother with the INT, but (and I can't stress strongly enough), **TAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR DATABASE** before making a change like that (does anything rely on the time part?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this syntax:

```
SELECT a.col1, b.col2, c.col3
FROM (([DFM report] AS a) LEFT JOIN [Audit report] AS b
    ON a.URN = b.URN)
LEFT JOIN [Accounting Calendar] AS c
    ON a.[Receipt Date] = c.Date
```

You have unbalanced parentheses, and the first table (and alias) need to wrapped in parentheses.  Also, you're missing a `SELECT` clause, though I will assume that your actual query does have one, and that you just forgot to copy it over.  If not, you'll need it.

Comment: Syntax error and missing operator are gone now but as soon as I click onto run, i get that "Enter Parameter Value" box. It looks like the box is selecting all the field names from my Select Statement

Comment: @Sk123 Well you never told me what columns you want to select.  Let me edit my answer.